# What is the meaning of this class in bootstrap : text-left-not-xs?

Tags: c#, bootstrapping

What is the meaning of this class in bootstrap : text-right-not-md?

```
<label class="control-label text-left-not-xs text-right-not-md">Example</label>
```

This is just an example of how it was used in the code. I am not sure about why we use `not-xs` as well `not-md`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will `align` the text to the left on all resolutions, except `mobile`. Titles for example on mobile are most of the time `center` aligned from design perspective.

Comment: It will align the text right everywhere except on medium screen such as laptops

Comment: Thank you so much.